# How to sort different lists based on their lindex values in TCL

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, tcl

How to sort different lists based on their lindex values please help me

Qstn:

Lets say i have an array variable call x.

**set $x(1) "4 5 7"**

**set $x(2) "1 3 9"**

**set $x(3) "9 1 5"**

i want to sort an array in the sorted order of first element in  list.

**lindex $x(2) 0 < lindex $x(1) 0 < lindex $x(3) 0**

So Here the answer i need is a new variable like $keys_sortd

**echo $keys_sorted**

**2 1 3**

I hope My question is clear. Please help me with the easiest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@siyb has the answer for Tcl 8.6. For 8.5:

```
% foreach {key value} [array get x] {lappend y [list $key $value]}
% set y
{1 {4 5 7}} {2 {1 3 9}} {3 {9 1 5}}
% lsort -index {1 0} $y
{2 {1 3 9}} {1 {4 5 7}} {3 {9 1 5}}
% foreach elem [lsort -index {1 0} $y] {lappend sorted_keys [lindex $elem 0]}
% set sorted_keys
2 1 3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
set x(1) "4 5 7"
set x(2) "1 3 9"
set x(3) "9 1 5"
set l [array get x]
puts $l
set sorted [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 $l]
puts $sorted
foreach {k v} $sorted {
        lappend result $k
}
puts $result

% tclsh8.6 sort.tcl
1 {4 5 7} 2 {1 3 9} 3 {9 1 5}
2 {1 3 9} 1 {4 5 7} 3 {9 1 5}
2 1 3
```

Hope that helps ;)

EDIT: Pre 8.6 code

```
foreach {k v} [array get x] {
        lappend unsorted [list $k [lindex $v 0]]
}
puts $unsorted
set sorted [lsort -index 1 $unsorted]
puts $sorted
foreach i $sorted {
        lappend result [lindex $i 0]
}
puts $result
```